lightning-map loosing zoom controls when on mobile device
I am trying to have lightning-map component work on both desktop and mobile. With the below code when on desktop view i get all the zoom controls, but when I am on mobile I loose it and also the map does not center.
<template if:true={selectedWorkOrderRecord}>
                    <div class="slds-p-around_xx-small">
                        <div class="slds-p-around_small">
                            <p><b>Incident Location: </b></p>
                            <div class="slds-p-around_x-small slds-m-top_x-small workorders-address-details-style">
                                <div class="slds-p-around_xx-small">
                                    <p>{selectedWorkOrderRecord.incidentLocation}</p>
                                </div>
                                <template if:false={onMobile}>
                                    <lightning-map map-markers={selectedWorkOrderRecord.mapMarkers} zoom-level="12"
                                        center={selectedWorkOrderRecord.mapCenter} class="slds-m-top_medium">
                                    </lightning-map>
                                </template>
                                <template if:true={onMobile}>
                                    <div class="map-container" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;">
                                        <lightning-map map-markers={selectedWorkOrderRecord.mapMarkers} zoom-level="12"
                                            center={selectedWorkOrderRecord.mapCenter}
                                            class="slds-m-top_small map-content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                        </lightning-map>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>

Here is the CSS -
.map-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.map-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Here is snip on both desktop and mobile -


Update -
This is how the mapCenter and mapMarkers look like -
"mapMarkers": [
    {
      "location": {
        "Street": "5689 York Road",
        "City": "Spring Grove",
        "State": "Pennsylvania",
        "PostalCode": "17362"
      },
      "title": "5689 York Road, Spring Grove, Pennsylvania, 17362"
    }
  ],
  "mapCenter": {
    "location": {
      "Street": "5689 York Road",
      "City": "Spring Grove",
      "State": "Pennsylvania",
      "PostalCode": "17362"
    }
  }


what does the selectedWorkOrderRecord.mapCenter look like?

@joacoiudica add mapCenter to the original post
